# How can I access Tkinter widgets outside of the init scope

Tags: python, object, tkinter, parameters, widget

Good evening,
I'm trying to do a little program with a GUI in python with Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class WindowCreator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        user_Ids = []
        # setting title
        root.title("Instagram Giveaway auto Filler")
        # setting window size
        width = 318
        height = 395
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        label_title = tk.Label(root)
        label_title["bg"] = "#000000"
        label_title["fg"] = "#ffd700"
        label_title["text"] = "Instagram Giveaway Auto Filler"
        label_title.place(x=50, y=10, width=201, height=31)

        label_urlPost = tk.Label(root)
        label_urlPost["bg"] = "#000000"
        label_urlPost["fg"] = "#ffd700"
        label_urlPost["text"] = "URL to post"
        label_urlPost.place(x=0, y=70, width=70, height=25)

        entry_urlPost = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_urlPost["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        entry_urlPost["fg"] = "#333333"
        entry_urlPost["text"] = "Entry"
        entry_urlPost.place(x=0, y=90, width=310, height=30)

        list_userIds = tk.Listbox(root)
        list_userIds["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        list_userIds["fg"] = "#333333"
        list_userIds.place(x=0, y=130, width=132, height=251)

        button_addId = tk.Button(root)
        button_addId["text"] = "New id"
        button_addId.place(x=140, y=320, width=70, height=25)
        button_addId["command"] = lambda: button_addId_command(user_Ids, root)

        button_comment = tk.Button(root)
        button_comment["text"] = "Comment"
        button_comment.place(x=140, y=350, width=70, height=25)
        button_comment["command"] = button_comment_command

        label_loggedIn = tk.Label(root)
        label_loggedIn["text"] = "Logged in: "
        label_loggedIn.place(x=150, y=150, width=70, height=25)

        label_postActive = tk.Label(root)
        label_postActive["text"] = "Post active?"
        label_postActive.place(x=150, y=190, width=70, height=25)

        label_nrEntries = tk.Label(root)
        label_nrEntries["text"] = "Number of Entries :"
        label_nrEntries.place(x=150, y=230, width=110, height=30)

        entry_nrEntries = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_nrEntries["text"] = "Entry"
        entry_nrEntries.place(x=270, y=230, width=33, height=30)

        check_loggedIn = tk.Checkbutton(root)
        check_loggedIn["text"] = ""
        check_loggedIn.place(x=210, y=150, width=41, height=30)
        check_loggedIn["offvalue"] = "0"
        check_loggedIn["onvalue"] = "1"
        check_loggedIn["command"] = check_loggedIn_command

        check_postActive = tk.Checkbutton(root)
        check_postActive["text"] = ""
        check_postActive.place(x=210, y=190, width=41, height=30)
        check_postActive["offvalue"] = "0"
        check_postActive["onvalue"] = "1"
        check_postActive["command"] = check_postActive_command

        button_login = tk.Button(root)
        button_login["text"] = "Login"
        button_login.place(x=250, y=150, width=44, height=30)
        button_login["command"] = button_login_command

        user_Ids = read_user_from_file("C:/Users/bruno/OneDrive/Documentos/userIds.txt")
        for users in user_Ids:
            list_userIds.insert('end', users)

    def refresh_user_list(self, user_list):
        global user_Ids
        for users in user_list:
            root.list_userIds.insert('end', users)


def read_user_from_file(file_path):
    user_txt = open(file_path, 'r')
    userIds = user_txt.readlines()
    return userIds


@staticmethod
def button_comment_command():
    print("command")


@staticmethod
def check_loggedIn_command():
    print("command")


@staticmethod
def check_postActive_command():
    print("command")


@staticmethod
def button_login_command():
    print("command")


def add_user_id(new_user, user_list, root, main_root):
    print(new_user)
    print(user_list)
    user_list.append(new_user)
    print(user_list)

    main_root.refresh_user_list(main_root, user_list)
    root.destroy()


def button_addId_command(user_list, main_root):
    root2 = tk.Toplevel(main_root)
    label_title = tk.Label(root2, text="Insert the new ID you want to add to the list ")
    entry_userID = tk.Entry(root2)
    button_register = tk.Button(root2, text="Register",
                                command=lambda: add_user_id(entry_userID.get(), user_list, root2, main_root))
    label_title.pack()
    entry_userID.pack()
    button_register.pack()
    root2.mainloop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    windows = WindowCreator(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

When I try to add a new user, I click the New Id button, and then a new windows pops up. In that new window, i've a entry widget and a button. I want to, when I click the register button in that new windows, to acess refresh_user_list, so I can refresh the ListBox widget of the first window list_userIds.
I'm having several troubles with passing objects, and acessing then within other scope.
I can't find a proper website that explains it. Can someone help me?
I tried to reduce the amount of code to post, but I couldn't

I tried to pass the objects as parameters ( the root ob

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\PycharmProjects\InstagramCommentBot\WindowCreator.py", line 135, in <lambda>
    button_register = tk.Button(root2, text="Register", command= lambda : add_user_id(entry_userID.get(), user_list, root2, main_root))
  File "C:\Users\bruno\PycharmProjects\InstagramCommentBot\WindowCreator.py", line 127, in add_user_id
    main_root.refresh_user_list(main_root,user_list)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2354, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'refresh_user_list'
```

jects of Tk()) but im always getting the error

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying mix OOP strategy while still attempting to make it all work in the global scope.  You need to pick one or the other.  In other words all you need to do is delete lines 3 and 4 and unindent everything that was in the class and that will fix it all for the most part.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I managed to notice it !Changing from java pure OOP to python is messing me a litle bit